# How to configure a custom RelProvider for Spring HATEOAS when using Spring Boot?

Tags: inheritance, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas, rel

I'm using the party model:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=...)
@JsonTypeInfo(use= JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public abstract class Party {

  @Column(updatable = false, insertable = false)
  private String type;

  ...
}

@Entity
public class Individual extends Party {
  ...
}

@Entity class Organization extends Party {
  ...
}
```

Spring Data REST responds like this:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "organizations": [
      {
        "type":"Organization",
        "name": "Foo Enterprises",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost/organization/2"
          },
          "organization": {
            "href": "http://localhost/organization/2"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "individuals": [
      {
        "type":"Individual",
        "name": "Neil M",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost/individual/1"
          },
          "individual": {
            "href": "http://localhost/individual/1"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But I need it to respond like this:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "parties": [
      {
        "type": "Organization",
        "name": "Foo Enterprises",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost/party/2"
          },
          "organization": {
            "href": "http://localhost/party/2"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Individual",
        "name": "Neil M",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost/party/1"
          },
          "individual": {
            "href": "http://localhost/party/1"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

To do so, I understand I [need to provide a custom RelProvider](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-344):

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Component
public class MyRelProvider implements RelProvider {

    public MyRelProvider() {}

    @Override
    public String getItemResourceRelFor(Class<?> aClass) {
        return "party";

    }

    @Override
    public String getCollectionResourceRelFor(Class<?> aClass) {
        return "parties";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return aClass.isAssignableFrom(Party.class);
    }
}
```

I tried configuring it in Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    RelProvider myRelProvider() {
        return new MyRelProvider();
    }
}
```

This doesn't work though. It seems to not get registered, or get registered correctly. See http://andreitsibets.blogspot.ca/2014/04/hal-configuration-with-spring-hateoas.html

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you annotated your controller classes with `@ExposesResourceFor`

From the [spring hateos docs](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-hateoas/0.20.x/reference/html/#spis.rel-provider)

> 3. SPIs
>
> 3.1. RelProvider API
>
> When building links you usually need to determine the relation type to be used > for the link. In most cases the relation type is directly associated with a (domain) type. We encapsulate the detailed algorithm to lookup the relation types behind a RelProvider API that allows to determine the relation types for single and collection resources. Here’s the algorithm the relation type is looked up:
>
> 1. If the type is annotated with [@Relation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/org/springframework/hateoas/core/Relation.html) we use the values configured in the annotation.
> 2. if not, we default to the uncapitalized simple class name plus an appended List for the collection rel.
> 3. in case the EVO inflector JAR is in the classpath, we rather use the plural of the single resource rel provided by the pluralizing algorithm.
> 4. @Controller classes annotated with @ExposesResourceFor (see EntityLinks for details) will transparently lookup the relation types for the type configured in the annotation, so that you can use relProvider.getSingleResourceRelFor(MyController.class) and get the relation type of the domain type exposed.
>
> A RelProvider is exposed as Spring bean when using @EnableHypermediaSupport automatically. You can plug in custom providers by simply implementing the interface and exposing them as Spring bean in turn.

Comment: what controller classes? This is Spring Data REST

Comment: on your interface that has the @RepositoryRestResource annotation

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and have a dirty solution in case you are interested. Implement private repositories for the subclasses like

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "parties")    
interface IndividualRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Individual, Long>{
}
```

Hope that will give you some temporary relief.